# Prevent Activity From Launching

Tags: android

Is there a good way of preventing an activity from launching? I'd like to build either a whitelist or blacklist of applications, then prevent those instances from being started.

One potential solution is to poll the running tasks every so often and shut them down, but this seems like it could eat through a lot of battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this doesnt count as a "GOOD WAY", could very well be as draining if not more so on your battery,  but in line with your polling method:

you could create a service that monitors the log cat (http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically)
need permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

then in your service something like (very crude):

```
private void readLogAndKill(){
 try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("Starting Activity")){
             if(line.contains("com.twitter.android"){
                  //kill twitter for example
              }
         }
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}
```

there may be someway to catch the "Starting Activity" events - or filter the log as you read it for just those msgs.

Comment: Interesting! I love good hacks like this. Not sure if this is quite as elegant as watching processes, but it's got me thinking about logs now. Thanks!

Comment: How do you kill processes for Android > 2.1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this is not supported with the SDK.